# How can I query or visualize the quorum slices of the Stellar network?

Tags: consensus, scp

I think I remember faintly that a while ago there was a JS-based visualization of the quorums between various validators on Stellar but I seem unable to find it again.

As far as I understand the algorithm, insight into quorum intersection is crucial for correct operation, so it would be interesting to see this metric on the deployed system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a stellar-core instance, it is possible to query the quorum set for any validator via an http request on port 11626:

Here is the endpoint your would use:
`quorum /quorum?[node=NODE_ID][&compact=true]`

And here is a description from the  [docs on the Stellar website](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html):

> returns information about the quorum for node NODE_ID (this node by
>   default). NODE_ID is either a full key (GABCD...), an alias ($name) or
>   an abbreviated ID (@GABCD). If compact is set, only returns a summary
>   version.

If you were interested in mapping out the entirety of the network, it is possible to run a stellar-core instance, and after a while you'd have access to a local SQL database of all the peers you've seen. Currently this schema does not include validator public key, but with a few tweaks that may be possible.